# iOS loading uiview inside another uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

So I have one UIview in xib of mainClass via the interface builder. I have made an IBOutet of UIIView and connected with uiview in the interface builde. Now in the ViewDidLoad method I am adding a subview to the UIView I put in Interface builder like this

```
GameScreen *gameScreen = [[GameScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"GameScreen" bundle:nil];  //the view beind added
[self.gameScreenView addSubview:[gameScreen view]]; //gameScreenView name of UIView
```

So [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsgbg.jpg) is what is happening - this is image from two diffrent builds (and haven't clicked on the button yet). In one build you can see the view loads up normally however on other it does (just shows the gray screen). Don't know why it is doing that. How can I fix this and why is it happening?

I previously posted a question over  here  but couldn't really get the problem across (its not an issue with animation as written in the question)

EDIT:

After playing around a bit with the code the UIView is not a issue its has to do something with the appdelegate and mainwindow.xib

thanks people for the help but it was just a silly mistake I had duplicate copies of xibs

Comment: is the gameScreenView allocated when you trying to add it, also why dont you implement the GameScreen as a UIView int the xib instead of UIViewController?

Comment: I don't quite understand--can you explain what actions you take to get the differing screen results?  Left image is bad, right image is good, I got that. Under what circumstances does each image occur?

Comment: Is a `GameScreen` a subclass of UIView? Why?

Comment: @WendiKidd these are diffrent builds from the same code..the "bad" screen so to speak only shows I build the project the second time like for instance 1st build works 2nd doesn't and then 3rd so on and so forth

Comment: gamescreen is not UIView its a UIViewController

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add your gameview to the gameview-screen. With what you're trying to accomplish, it sounds like doing:

```
[self.view addSubview:gameScreen.view];
```

would be better.

Although I'm not sure. You might need to elaborate on what exactly the self.gameScreenView is.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was able to solve the problem, I had two xibs with same name

Answer (score 1):

There is something amiss here. It looks like you are loading a whole new controller just to get the main view out of the nib. Do you need gameScreen as a whole new controller?

```
NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameScreen" owner:nil options:nil];
[self.gameScreenView addSubview:[views objectAtIndex:0]];
```

This loads all the views of the nib into an array without the messiness of dealing how a controller loads a nib. It might work better for you.

Comment: It's usually pretty useful with a ViewController. To listen for touches and other view-events.

Comment: thank you for the answer I just had two xibs with same names